# How do I use the debugger in OCaml with VS Code on ubuntu?

Tags: ocaml, visual-studio-code

I installed VS Code with the OCaml extension (with merlin) and I would like to debug a simple program, but I can't. When I call "display"/"debug", the debugging panes are displayed; but, if I click on the green arrow to launch the program, nothing happens.

Here is my launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        
        {
            "name": "OCaml",
            "type": "ocamldebug",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/leap",
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "stopOnEntry": false
        }
    ]
}
```

(leap is the name of the executable created by the task). tasks.json:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "ocamlc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["-o", "leap", "essai1.ml"],
    "showOutput": "always"
}
```

Comment: probably, an issue tracker of the tool is a better place to get support on such issues.

Comment: hello, I don't agree with you : the work should be done well if the tool is well configured, but I lack of tutorials. the correct behavior of vscode or vscode-ocaml is not in cause.

Comment: This is not because people here don't want to help you :) I wish I could, but you're asking about a very specific tool, that is not really popular in the community. I wouldn't expect that many people here use `vscode`, so you are basically fishing in a place where there are no fish. So it is better to ask an author (an author of the extension, or tool). Because, what I read from your question is: "I've opened some tool, click a button and nothing happens..."

Comment: ok, thanks, now I know what to expect... and maybe I will follow your advice, after all.