# VS Code error: "Cannot find debug adapter for type 'ocamldebug'"

Tags: visual-studio-code, ocaml

I am trying to run files on visual studio code that are in OCaml but it does not seem to work. How can I fix?

I was expecting it to run but I keep getting errors. [Cannot find debug adapter for type 'ocamldebug'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gR5YS.jpg)

My launch.json file is:

```
    {
        "name": "OCaml",
        "type": "ocamldebug",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/main.d.byte",
        "console": "internalConsole",
        "stopOnEntry": false
    }
```

I have [the OCaml platform extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ocamllabs.ocaml-platform).

Answer (score 0):

The extension you're using doesn't contribute any debuggers. See for yourself: There's no `contributes > debuggers` field in [its pacakge.json](https://github.com/ocamllabs/vscode-ocaml-platform/blob/master/package.json)- at least- not at the time of this writing. I'm assume you're trying to follow some tutorial (perhaps [How do I use the debugger in OCaml with VS Code on ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42275051/11107541)) that was written for [the `hackwaly.vscode-ocaml` extension](https://github.com/hackwaly/vscode-ocaml), which is now deprecated in favour of the extension you're using. It itself recommends usage of [`hackwaly.ocamlearlybird`](https://github.com/hackwaly/ocamlearlybird/) for debugging purposes in VS Code. You can find [an example launch configuration for that in its readme](https://github.com/hackwaly/ocamlearlybird#example-launch-configuration).